# How to define summation on a general space

Tags: real-analysis, summation

We have the notation of summation on the space of Real numbers. Now I want to define the notation of summation on a more general space (for example, space of real-valued function).

What is the general procedure to define such a notation ? Which set of criteria that I have to verify to ensure that my definition of summation is logically accepted ?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about 'group'. Just check it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)